# After logout also i am able to open the pages by clicking on back button of browser

Tags: php

As i asked above, How to not make the pages open even after logout? i checked so many question and solutions but none of them worked for me, i am afraid i might be done something wrong don't know. But this issue is because of browser cache as i read in previous solutions. Please help me out with any solutions.

i'll be posting my code below :

session.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];  
    include_once 'includes/connection.php';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin");  
    $stmt->execute();   
    $dets = $stmt->fetch();
?>
```

login.php

```
session_start();
require_once 'includes/connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['uname']))
{
     $user_name = $_POST['uname'];
     $password = md5(trim($_REQUEST['password']));
     try
     {
         $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE BINARY username=:username");
         $stmt->bindParam(':username', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->execute();
         $row = $stmt->fetch();
         $count = $stmt->rowCount();
         if($count > 0)
         {
           if($row['password']==$password)
           {
               $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
               $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
               $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
               echo "1"; // log in
           }
           else
           {                
              echo "Username or Password does not exist."; // wrong details
           }
         }
       }        
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {
         die("ERROR: Could not prepare/execute query: " . $e->getMessage());
       }
    }

?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: you must require_once your session.php file in all pages.

Comment: add session_start() in your login.php file

Comment: yes i have added session to all pages and also i have missed those two lines while adding here to login.php . But i have added in my code

Comment: please cross verify your session is destroying or not by echo the $_SESSION['id'] variable

Comment: yes it display correct id and now its working i was made wrong redirection at desktop view logout. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

After using session_destroy(), the session is destroyed behind the scenes. For some reason this doesn't affect the values in $_SESSION, which was already populated for this request, but it will be empty in future requests.

You can manually clear $_SESSION if you so desire ($_SESSION = [];).

Comment: i tried same as you suggested but still after logout, when i press back button of browser it opens the page